# How to check if a person pinged themselves discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to check if a person pinged themselves. I have a command called &pat and I want to make it so you can't pat yourself. I get the person that should be patted like this, you have to do `&pat @{user}`.

```
var pattedone = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Then I want to check if the author didn't ping himself. I've tried multiple ways, but all of them somehow led to setting the message author to the pinged user.

```js
if (`${pattedone}` === `${message.author}`) {
 message.reply(`you can't pat yourself`);
} else {
 message.reply(`can be patted`);
}
```

Then the bot always responded that the user can't be patted, even tho I pinged my alt. It also responded like if it was my alt who sent the message, so if my username is User#0000 and my alt is User#0001, and I do &pat @User#0001, it responded with: @User#0001 (my alt), you can't pat yourself. I also tried using this:

```
if(pattedone === message.author)
```

and the rest of the code being the same as above, but it led to the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two users, the best way is to use their IDs, instead of comparing the objects.

```js
if(pattedone.id === message.author.id) {
    message.reply(`you can't pat yourself`)
} else {
    message.reply(`can be patted`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `message.author` returns a `User` object, but `message.mentions.members.first()` returns a *`GuildMember`* object. Instead:

```js
var pattedone = message.mentions.users.first(); // get a collection of users instead of members
if (pattedone.id === message.author.id) {
   // code...
};
```